# how to make my command prompt look like [hostname@localhost] not [c:\users\hostname]

Tags: cmd, localhost

how to make my cmd / command prompt look like [hostname@localhost] not [c:\users\hostname]

[image: Pic. 1: illustrate what will i try to get]
[image: Pic. 2:refer to my command propt]

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. To be on topic on [SO] your question should contain at least an own coding attempt. As is, it is better suited on [su]. See the help of `prompt /?` and try `prompt [%USERNAME%@%COMPUTERNAME%] $P $g`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prompt command.

```
prompt [hostname@localhost]$$$P
```

For more info on prompt, type **prompt /?** in your cmd window.

And you can dynamically include the username like this:

`prompt [%USERNAME%@localhost]$$$P`